# socketio4net-problems with proxy

Tags: sockets, ssl, proxy, socketio4net

I have been asked to take over a project where the previous developer had used socketio4net,

hence I learnt of the socketio4 project only now.

the problem my employer is facing is clients having proxy servers.

we have installed our product(client side) on clinics which uses socketio4net and websocket. 
 They all connect to our main azure server for sending data. In clinics without proxy,we are not facing any issues. but those with proxy server, our service is not even starting.

if we have to implement the ssl process, it will be a big overhead for us

how do we achieve  ssl and proxy settings for sockets in general? does socketio4net provide any other options?

do I have change to http classes like webclient?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with proxies and school's in particular, the vast majority turned out to be a firewall based issue. 
What port are you using, 80, 443 or something else? If that is the issue, the clinics would need to either whitelist your server ip, or allow the ip:port combo you've set.

For a quick test at the clinics that have issues - I would try these two sites (probably others sites you can find too):

http://websocketstest.com/ - tests for ports 80, 8080, 443 with and without ssl - do all or only some work?
(this site is also great for a end-user at the site to run for you, as you can get a results link - double bonus points!)

http://www.websocket.org/echo.html

Are both of the sites above able to connect?

Hope that helps...